# Random Forrest data prediction (in R) and data bias

Tags: r, machine-learning, predictive-models, random-forest

I have a data set from 2014 to the present and I am trying to classify stock performance based on whether the stock outperforms the market by 5% or not (1 vs 0).
I am using a random forest model in R (`randomForest`).

I split my data into a training and test set (70% vs 30% using random stratified sampling, using `createDataPartition`). I then generate the probability of a stock beating the market (from 0 to 1).
When I run my model on the test data (the 30%) I achieve good results (vertical axis is performance, horizontal is generated probability of beating the market):
[image]
However, when I hold back a year or 6m period (at the beginning or end of my sample) my model performs very poorly and interestingly the probability of beating the market doesn't ever rise about 0.55:

[image]

Could there be some sort of bias in my data that is causing samples at the beginning or end to be unrepresentative or could I be over fitting my model?